# Getting Outlook 2010 to NOT use VPN

Tags: vpn, microsoft-outlook-2010, cisco-vpn-client

I have a work laptop that I connect to my company's server through a Cisco VPN Client, I also have a company email that I use Outlook 2010 to access but it is only accessible from outside i.e. not from the internal server that all my other work stuff is on.

So, Outlook works like a charm when I've got the computer just connected to the internet but as soon as I'm connect to the VPN, Outlook stops working because it tries to use the VPN which won't connect to the email server.

Let's say that there's a good reason for this and theres no changing what my IT Security people set the server to have access to or not.

Is there a way to get Microsoft Outlook to only use the internet Wi-Fi connection weather I'm connected to the VPN or not?

I want everything else to use the VPN as that's the only way anything else works, Outlook is basically the only program allowed through the firewall.

I've always had this problem but I'm getting sick of disconnecting the VPN to check my email and then reconnecting it to get back to work.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do this. One of the simpler is to make a shortcut that launches to the correct outlook using the ip address and not the DNS name. Example, you currently could be going to my.workplace.com which translates to 201.12.10.1  Then make a shortcut for launching outlook that uses 201.12.10.1  Since did not use a DNS resolve, this may work.

Comment: That sounds promising, how does one make such a shortcut? Sorry, this is a few levels above my skill set.

Comment: Easiest way is to ask your IT department.  There is a reasonable chance they have already made the shortcut.  Even if not, one of them might help out and make it for you.

Comment: If you want to do it yourself. There are two forms for outlook, one is  called OWA or outlook web access. If that is what you are using,  make a copy of your outlook icon, look at its properties. if it starts with https://mailbox.MYCompany.com/ Then ping the mailbox address. login to the vpn, ping again. If the numbers are different, then that is going to be the source of your problem.  Copy the current outlook shortcut  & change the mailbox.mycompany.com to the ping address from not being on the vpn.

Comment: Gotcha, but I'm using full-on Microsoft Office Outlook 2010, on Windows 10, not OWA. Sorry that wasn't totally clear in my original post. Thanks by the way :)

Comment: if using 2010 full, go into file account settings. Do you have a link and a box saying "access this on the web".  Copy that link and it is your owa access.  Otherwise, will need your IT department to help with this.

Comment: Yeah, no such link. Guess it's back to the drawing board.